# How to print (or see) i, j, f and o gates values and dimensions while using BasicLSTMCell tensorflow for sequence classification?

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am using [this](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/dynamic_rnn.py) tensorflow example written by Aymeric Damien to classify some sequences using BasicLSTMCell. How can I change this example to print i, j, f and o (gates) values and shapes at each time step during the training?

Thanks!

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I can run the example and see it is working. I can also print the outputs and hidden states as they are returned by the BasicLSTMCell. However, I cannot dig deeper. I would like to see the gates values (and other results after each calculations) step by step and at each time step to get the clear understanding, like what I do when I am debugging a code.

Comment: I also changed the "return new_h, new_state" line in BasicLSTMCell to return new_h, new_state, i, j, f, o and in the example script changed the line number 128 to:

Comment: line number 128 to "outputs, states, i_val, j_val, f_val, o_val = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32,
                                sequence_length=seqlen)" and line 151 to "return tf.matmul(outputs, weights['out']) + biases['out'], states, i_val, j_val, f_val, o_val" and line 153 to "pred, states, i_val, j_val, f_val, o_val = dynamicRNN(x, seqlen, weights, biases,seq_max_len,n_hidden)". But didn't work

Comment: File "rnn.py", line 1327, in static_rnn
    state_size=cell.state_size)
  File "rnn.py", line 263, in _rnn_step
    _maybe_copy_some_through)
  File "deprecation.py", line 454, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "control_flow_ops.py", line 2057, in cond
    orig_res_f, res_f = context_f.BuildCondBranch(false_fn)
  File "control_flow_ops.py", line 1895, in BuildCondBranch
    original_result = fn()
  File "rnn.py", line 233, in _maybe_copy_some_through
    new_output, new_state = call_cell()
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)